# How to show array of objects with useSelector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

What should I use instead of `useSelector` or `mapStateToProps`? Those run multiple times(`array.lenght`) and change all values to the last one.

I have an e-commerce app,
`ProductDetails` component contains product reviews and I map those to the `ProductReview` component to get user info that gets from user Id.

**ProductDetails.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ProductReview from "../components/ProductReview";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getProductDetailsById } from "../Store/actions/productActions";

export default function ProductDetails(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const product = useSelector((state) => state.product)

  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = props.match.params;
    const payload = {
      params: {
        id,
      },
    };
    dispatch(getProductDetailsById(payload));
    
  },[dispatch, props.match.params]);

  return (
    <div>
      {product.productDetails.reviews && 
        product.productDetails.reviews.map((item , index) =>    
        (
           <li key={item.userId}>
              <ProductReview key={item.userId} userId={item.userId} 
                             review={item.review}/>
           </li> )
               )}
        )}
</div>
  );
}
```

**ProductReview.js**

```js
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getUSerById } from '../Store/actions/userAction';
import {useDispatch , useSelector} from 'react-redux';

export default function ProductReview(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
  
const {userId} = props;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const payload = {
      params : {
        userId
      }
    }
    dispatch(getUSerById(payload))  
  },[userId]);

    
 return (
    <div>
        {user && user.user.firstName} : {props.review}
    </div>
  )
}
```

this part of the code runs multiple times and
**changes all user info values** (user first name) to the last one.
**All product reviews `firstName`s change to the last one ** all same name

```js
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
```

Is there any way to get rid of this??
It runs currently when using Axios in the `ProductReview` component with `useState()`, but I want to use redux.

userReducer.js

```js
import { userConstants } from "../actions/Types";

const initState = {
  user: {},
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export default (state = initState, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload)
  switch(action.type){
    case userConstants.GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS:
      return state = {
        ...state,
        user : action.payload.user,
        loading: false,
        error: null
      }
    case userConstants.GET_USER_BY_ID_FAILURE:
      return state = {
        state,
        error: action.payload.error
      }  
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `userId` inside the ProductReview's useEffect dependencies.

Comment: A part from that I didn't understand what happens here. If you update the `state.user` inside redux store with `getUSerById`, it's normal that the selector `const user = useSelector(state => state.user)` returns the last user's value. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What can you use instead of `useSelector` or `mapStateToProps`? Well, I suppose you could directly access the redux state via the `store` object, but that is generally ***not*** recommended. Other than this it's a bit unclear what the issue is. For what you are mapping in `ProductDetails` you send the same `userId` as a prop to each element, so I would expect all `ProductReview` components to have the same prop value.

Comment: @MarcoNisi all reviews return with the same first name(the last one). But they should have the different first name.

Comment: share your reducers logic.

Comment: probably you only have that one user in your data and that's why you get that

Comment: @DrewReese , in ProductDetails I map userId and review and send them to ProductReview , review shows correctly as each time it passes, but the user first name changes to the last one

Comment: Looks like you've only space for one user in state: `user: {},`.

Comment: @phry, No, it's Not.

Comment: @DrewReese, Each time return one user info

Comment: @ShahrzadGh from what I see you store only one `user` reference inside your redux store. So for each `dispatch(getUSerById(payload))` you overwrite the previous, resulting in having always the last one user for each review. You have to store all users, maybe using an array or a well structured map.

Comment: So what is the issue then if there is only one user info each time? Something isn't making sense here. Each iteration of `reviews` array, or each time the entire reviews array is rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese, each review send to ProductReview with a userId. dispatch(getUserById(payload)) get userinfo contains firstName and useSelector return user firstName . Is there any miss understanding for me? useSelector runs as count as reviews and changes all first name to last one.

Comment: Again, it seems you've a single user object in state. Are you expecting each `dispatch(getUserById(payload))` to be a different user? If so then you need to store ***all*** of them in state, not just the last one fetched.

Comment: @MarcoNisi So Should I change the reducer and return an array of users. I think it doesn't make sense. why it does overwrite my values?

Comment: @ShahrzadGh I posted an answer that should resolve your issue, please check it. If it's not clear I can provide further explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in the comments you need to store all users in your redux store in some way.
For example you could do something like the following:

1. Change `initState` with:

   ```
   const initState = {
     users: {},
     loading: false,
     error: null
   };
   ```
2. Change `GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS` reducer with
   (please pay attention that I'm using `user.id`, but maybe your id is stored in some other property):

   ```
   case userConstants.GET_USER_BY_ID_SUCCESS:
     return state = {
       ...state,
       users: { ...state.users, [action.payload.user.id]: action.payload.user },
       loading: false,
       error: null
     }
   ```
3. Change useSelector with:

   ```
   const users = useSelector(state => state.users)
   ```
4. Add:

   ```
   const user = users[props.userId]
   ```

In this way you should have the correct user. If I miss something please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative. But like those two , this will run multiple times as well. But I'm gonna share it anyway:

```
var client;
store.subscribe(() => {
  client = store.getState().client;
});
```

Putting this piece of code on top of your component, giving it global scope, causes for this client variable to be accessible in your component. Everytime the store is changed , subscribe method will read into it and cause the funciton inside of it to render and that leads to getState() function getting the client part of the state that is stored in store. Now you have a variable to use in your component which will be updated whenever the store is changed.

Comment: Thank you, But I think I should change my question.